# Spring MVC Controller always return 404 for POST request

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a simple web application.

What it does is: using ajax to post a request to server with post method.

The controller is work well with GET method, but when I changed it to POST method, it always return 404 (Not Found).

Is there any solution or suggestion for check?

Comment: show your controller and dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: You need to post some code, try to put together an [mcve](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwifqf69gbTPAhViB8AKHSmNAdQQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AFQjCNEkKReghNZHBJSaky_hwPskMmG0ww&sig2=FnTPeMm0-ChgNJtzt1jlew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution for this problem,

You need to include csrf token in the header of AJAX request, because by default Spring enable CSRF security feature.

You can find more information here: [Ajax and JSON Requests](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax)